# Distribution of POI query result

Tags: query, point-of-interest, distribution

There are a lot of POIS in the database with fileds `id` `name` `address` `lon` `lat`.

When we tried to query some points for a given bounding box, it is simple to build the accordingly sql and get the results, however we found that the distribution of the result are not desired(see the left image below):

[image]

While we want the results of every page distributed evenly in the view port like the image in the right.

Is this possible?

Comment: What is actually being displayed in the result - the bounding box extent or the extent of the result? If the bounding box, point distribution is going to depend on the proximity of the points themselves within the box. If you want things to always spread out and 'fill' the view as on the right, you need to select by bounding box and then get the extent of the resulting selection to use as the view extent.

Comment: I know your meaning, first select points by the condition and then calculate the bounding box of the result set, and then set the view port to fit the bbox, however the zoom level can not be increased more, in the above example, both of them are at the 20 zoom.

Comment: If that's the case I don't think there's a solution if you're already at max zoom/scale; the points are simply too close together for the maximum scale/resolution available. If you can indicate the software/API/etc. you are using, someone with expertise in it might know of or be able to suggest a workaround.